# I want to implement Huffman tree using the data structure "heap", but I'm confused about these errors

Tags: c++

I think it is not caused by library losing.And I am sure that I have implemented every function I declare.

The most of the codes are from the book < Data structures and algorithm analysis in c++ >.And I have searched many other similar questions,but I 'm still confused.
Can anyone tell me how can I solve the problem?

heap.h

```
#pragma once
template <typename E, typename Comp>
class heap
{
private:
    E* Heap;        //Pointer to the heap array
    int maxsize;    //Maximum size of the heap
    int n;          //Number of elements now in the heap
        //Helper function to put element in its correct place,and that moves the father node down
    void siftdown(int pos);
public:
    heap(E* h, int num, int max);
    int size()const;
    bool isLeaf(int pos)const;
    int leftchild(int pos)const;
    int rightchild(int pos)const;
    int parent(int pos)const;
    void buildHeap();
    void insert(const E& it);
    E removefirst();
    E remove(int pos);
};
```

heap.cpp

```
#include "heap.h"
#include<assert.h>

//Swap two elements in the container
template<typename E>
void swap(E*array,int pos1,int pos2) {
    int temp = array[pos1];
    array[pos1] = array[pos2];
    array[pos2] = temp;
}

//Heap class
// E is the element in heap
//Comp is a class used to compare two elements
//Helper function to put element in its correct place,and that moves the father node down
    template <typename E, typename Comp>
    void heap<E, Comp>::siftdown(int pos) {
        while (!isLeaf(pos)) {//Stop if pos is a leaf
            int j = leftchild(pos);
            int rc = rightchild(pos);
            if ((rc < n) && Comp::prior(Heap[rc], Heap[j]))
                j = rc;     //Set j to greater child's value
            if (Comp::prior(Heap[pos], Heap[j]))
                return; //Done
            swap(Heap, pos, j);
            pos = j;        //Move down
        }
    }
    template <typename E, typename Comp>
    heap<E,Comp>::heap(E* h, int num, int max) {
        Heap = h;
        n = num;
        maxsize = max;
    }
    //Return current heap size
    template <typename E, typename Comp>
    int heap<E, Comp>::size()const {
        return n;
    }
    //True if pos is a leaf
    template <typename E, typename Comp>
    bool heap<E, Comp>::isLeaf(int pos)const {
        return ((pos >= n / 2) && (pos < n));
    }
    //Return leftchild position
    template <typename E, typename Comp>
    int heap<E,Comp>::leftchild(int pos)const {
        return 2 * pos + 1;
    }
    //Return rightchild position
    template <typename E, typename Comp>
    int heap<E,Comp>::rightchild(int pos)const {
        return 2 * pos + 2;
    }
    //Return parent position
    template <typename E, typename Comp>
    int heap<E,Comp>::parent(int pos)const {
        return (pos - 1) / 2;
    }
    //Heapify contents of Heap
    template <typename E, typename Comp>
    void heap<E, Comp>:: buildHeap() {
        for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            siftdown(i);
        }
    }
    //Insert "it" into the heap
    template <typename E, typename Comp>
    void heap<E,Comp>::insert(const E& it) {
        assert(n < maxsize);    //Terminate if heap is full
        int curr = n++;
        Heap[curr] = it;        //Start at end of heap
        //Move up until curr's parent > curr
        while ((curr != 0) && (Comp::prior(Heap[curr], Heap[parent(curr)]))) {
            swap(Heap, curr, parent(curr));
            curr = parent(curr);
        }
    }

    template <typename E, typename Comp>
    E heap<E, Comp>::removefirst() {
        assert(n > 0);      //Interrupt if heap is empty
        swap(Heap, 0, --n);     //Swap first with last value.
        if (n != 0)siftdown(0);     //Siftdown new root val
        return Heap[n];         //Return deleted value
    }

    template <typename E, typename Comp>
    E heap<E, Comp>::remove(int pos) {
        assert((pos >= 0) && (pos < n));  //Intertupt if it is in bad position
        if (pos == n - 1)n--;       //Last element,no work to do
        else {
            swap(Heap, pos, --n);       //Swap with last value
            while ((pos != 0) && (Comp::prior(Heap[pos], Heap[parent(pos)]))) {
                swap(Heap, pos, parent(pos));       //Push up large key
                pos = parent(pos);
            }
            if (n != 0)siftdown(pos);       //Push down small key
        }
        return Heap[n];
    }
```

main.cpp

```
#include"heap.h"
#include<time.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
//Huffman tree node abstract base class
template<typename E> 
class HuffNode {
public:
    virtual ~HuffNode(){}       //Base destructor
    virtual int weight() = 0;   //Return frequency
    virtual bool isLeaf() = 0;  //Determine type
};

template<typename E>    //Leaf node subclass
class LeafNode :public HuffNode<E> {
private:
    E it;           //Value
    int wgt;        //Weight
public:
    LeafNode(const E& val, int freq) {
        it = val;
        wgt = freq;
    }
    int weight() { return wgt; }
    E val() { return it; }
    bool isLeaf() { return true; }
    ~LeafNode(){}
};

template<typename E>        //Internal node subclass
class IntlNode : public HuffNode<E> {
private:
    HuffNode<E>* lc;        //Left child
    HuffNode<E>* rc;        //Right child
    int wgt;                //Subtree weight
public:
    IntlNode(HuffNode<E>* l, HuffNode<E>* r) {
        wgt = l->weight() + r->weight();
        lc = l;
        rc = r;
    }
    int weight() { return wgt; }
    bool isLeaf() { return false; }
    HuffNode<E>* left()const { return lc; }
    void setLeft(HuffNode<E>* b) {
        lc = b;
    }
    HuffNode<E>* right()const { return rc; }
    void setRight(HuffNode<E>* b) {
        rc = b;
    }
    ~IntlNode(){}
};

template<typename E>
class HuffTree {
private:
    HuffNode<E>* Root;      //Tree root
public:
    HuffTree(E& val, int freq) {    //Leaf constructor
        Root = new LeafNode<E>(val, freq);
    }
    //Internal node construtor
    HuffTree(HuffTree<E>* l, HuffTree<E>* r) {
        Root = new IntlNode<E>(l->root(), r->root());
    }
    HuffTree() { Root = NULL; }
    ~HuffTree(){}
    HuffNode<E>* root() { return Root; }
    int weight() { return Root->weight(); }
    };

template<typename E>
class minTreeComp {
public:
    bool prior(HuffTree<E>* a, HuffTree<E>* b) {
        return b->weight() - a->weight();
    }
};


//Build a Huffman tree from a collection of frequencies
template<typename E>
HuffTree<E>* buildHuff(HuffTree<E>** TreeArray, int count) {
    heap<HuffTree<E>*, minTreeComp<E>>* forest =
        new heap<HuffTree<E>*, minTreeComp<E>>(TreeArray, count, count);
    HuffTree<char> *temp1, *temp2, *temp3 = NULL;
    while (forest->size() > 1) {
        temp1 = forest->removefirst();  //Pull first two trees
        temp2 = forest->removefirst();  //off the list
        temp3 = new HuffTree<E>(temp1, temp2);  
        forest->insert(temp3);          //Put the new tree back on list
        delete temp1;       //Must delete the remnants  
        delete temp2;       //of the trees we created
    }
    return temp3;
}

template<typename E>
void traverse(HuffNode<E>* forest) {
    if (forest->isLeaf() == true) {
        cout <<((LeafNode<E>*)forest)->val()<<" : "<<forest->weight() << endl;
    }
    else {
        traverse(((IntlNode<E>*)forest)->left());
        traverse(((IntlNode<E>*)forest)->right());
    }
}

int main() {
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));
    char ch = 'A';
    HuffTree<char>** forests= new HuffTree<char>*[10];
    //vector<HuffTree<char>*>trees;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        ch += 1;
       forests[i]= new HuffTree<char>(ch,rand() % 50 + 1);
}
    HuffTree<char>* forest = buildHuff(forests, 4);
    traverse(forest->root());
}
```

I have four errors:

> 1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall heap *,class minTreeComp >::heap *,class minTreeComp >(class HuffTree * *,int,int)" (??0?$heap@PAV?$HuffTree@D@@V?$minTreeComp@D@@@@QAE@PAPAV?$HuffTree@D@@HH@Z) referenced in function "class HuffTree * __cdecl buildHuff(class HuffTree * *,int)"
>
> 1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall heap *,class minTreeComp >::size(void)const " (?size@?$heap@PAV?$HuffTree@D@@V?$minTreeComp@D@@@@QBEHXZ) referenced in function "class HuffTree * __cdecl buildHuff(class HuffTree * *,int)" (??$buildHuff@D@@YAPAV?$HuffTree@D@@PAPAV0@H@Z)
>
> 1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall heap *,class minTreeComp >::insert(class HuffTree * const &)" (?insert@?$heap@PAV?$HuffTree@D@@V?$minTreeComp@D@@@@QAEXABQAV?$HuffTree@D@@@Z) referenced in function "class HuffTree * __cdecl buildHuff(class HuffTree * *,int)" (??$buildHuff@D@@YAPAV?$HuffTree@D@@PAPAV0@H@Z)
>
> 1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class HuffTree * __thiscall heap *,class minTreeComp >::removefirst(void)" (?removefirst@?$heap@PAV?$HuffTree@D@@V?$minTreeComp@D@@@@QAEPAV?$HuffTree@D@@XZ) referenced in function "class HuffTree * __cdecl buildHuff(class HuffTree * *,int)" (??$buildHuff@D@@YAPAV?$HuffTree@D@@PAPAV0@H@Z)